# is it possible to use gmail as backend database for my app using javamail api?

Tags: android, database-design, jakarta-mail, backend, gmail-imap

javamail api is used for sending and receiving emails automatically without prompting user for to & from addresses and without using other third -party email apps(i.e, without using Intent.ACTION_SEND).
I'm creating a simple app where a teacher can upload an assignment and students can download it.as i don't have enough knowledge in backend i thought an idea which is: By using javamail the app sends an email with attachment as the file selected by teacher to a gmail inbox and when students want to download the file the app will then fetch mail from the inbox and downloads it . is this idea is possible?

the only problem i can figure out is Google may force me to change the linked email account password frequently due to their over zealous "suspicious activity" polices. In essence it treats repeated imap requests from different places within a short time frame as "suspicious activity". As they assume you (the email account holder) can only be in one place at a time. When google systems detect "suspicious activity" it will prevent further emails until you change the password. As i have hard coded the password into the app i'll have to re-release the app each time this happens, not ideal. what's the solution to this ? * sorry for my bad english

Comment: Hard coding the password in the app is a bad idea, and in general trying to hide it in the app is at best "security through obscurity".  JavaMail is probably not the best choice for what you're trying to do.  Better would be to write your own server-side program that allows the teacher to login and upload a file, and then allows each student to login and download the file.

Comment: I agree with Bill on that your way of using JavaMail as a Backend store is probalby not the best choice. If you'd want to use javamail, why not send out the assignment to the students by email?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I think I have to use google drive api for this instead of javamail.